# Flutter close child screen and navigate to another screen automatically

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using bottom tab-navigation and my screens have the following logic:

```
Screen A
 -> Button Open Screen B
 -> Button Open Screen C
Screen B
 -> Button Open Child Screen B
    -> Button Open Screen C
```

I can navigate from `Screen A` to `Screen B` through code using `widget.mainTabController.animateTo(1);` and it works great.

What I need now is to navigate from `Screen B` to `Screen A` after the `Child Screen B` has been closed.

```
class ScreenB extends StatefulWidget {
  final TabController mainTabController;

  ScreenB(TabController mainTabController)
      : this.mainTabController = mainTabController;

  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<ScreenB> 
{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // ...
        GridView.builder(
            // ...
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)
            {
                Entry entry = this.entries[index];
                return entry.build(context);
            }
        );
    }
}

class Entry extends State<ScreenB>
{
    Widget build(BuildContext context) 
    {
        // ... 
        onTap: () async {
            // Opens the Screen B Child
            final result = await Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ScreenBChild(),
                ),
            );
            
            // Should go back to Screen A but does nothing
            if (result)
                widget.mainTabController.animateTo(0);
        );
    }
}
```

After the screen "Child Screen B" has been closed, I'm back to `Screen B` and the code `widget.mainTabController.animateTo(0)`, although is being triggered, nothing happens, the screen doesn't change. Also no error is thrown in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

1. The `Entry` class must be converted into a Stateless (or Stateful, as you wish) class
2. The class should receive the `mainTabController` upon its initialization
3. We have to apply a Delay before trigger the animation to move to another screen

With that said, the `Entry` is called like this:

```
Entry entry = new Entry(mainTabController: widget.mainTabController);
```

And the class was converted to:

```
class Entry extends StatelessWidget {
  final TabController mainTabController;

  Entry({Key key, this.mainTabController}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) 
  {
    // ...
    onTap: () async {
        final result = await Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ScreenBChild(),
            ),
        );
        
        if (result)
        {
            await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 300), () => 
            { 
                this.mainTabController.animateTo(0);
            });
        }           
    }
  }
}
```